# What is the difference between true and enable values of the ImplicitUsings property?

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

According to Visual Studio's QuickInfo tooltip,

> Enable implicit global usings for the C# project. Possible values are
> true, enable, and disable.

When to use enable and when to use true?

[image]

Comment: There is a note in the [MSBuild properties page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#implicitusings) that says that "enable" and "true" should be functionally the same, but it doesn't provide an answer as to _why_ there are two options, or if they somehow act different.

Comment: It might be a case of https://thedailywtf.com/articles/what_is_truth_0x3f_

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#implicitusings),

> Set this property to `true` or `enable` to enable implicit global using directives. To disable implicit global using directives, remove the property or set it to `false` or `disable`.

The wording here suggests that `true` and `enable` mean the same thing, and `false` and `disable` mean the same thing.

Comment: By right clicking the ImplicitUsing tag, then selecting Go To Definition, I found no "false" value available for this property.

Comment: @usefulBee I use VSCode so I am unable to "Go To Definition". In any case, what is the problem? Nothing is preventing you from putting in a value that isn't "available". From my experiments, it seems like anything that isn't "true" or "enable" will disable it.

Comment: Use F12 as an alternative to view the metadata of any element or type.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this class: [ImplicitUsingsEnabledValueProvider](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/main/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Managed/ProjectSystem/Properties/InterceptedProjectProperties/ReferencesPage/ImplicitUsingsEnabledValueProvider.cs), `enable` and `true`, `disable` and `false` just have the same meaning, and according to the code, these words are case insensitive.